# How come this regex wont produce a group / capture for the numbers?

Tags: c#, regex

```
        Regex regexObj = new Regex(
        @"([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*)(:)(([-+*%])?(\d*\.?\d*)?)*"
           , RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

        var subjectString = "a:123+456;b:456;";
        Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
        while (matchResults.Success) {
            for (int i = 1; i < matchResults.Groups.Count; i++) {
                Group grp = matchResults.Groups[i];
                if (grp.Success) {
                    Console.WriteLine("st:" + grp.Index + ", len:" + grp.Length + ", val:" + grp.Value);
                }
            }
            matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
        }
```

Output:

st:0, len:2, val:.a

st:2, len:1, val::

st:6, len:0, val:

st:6, len:0, val:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because by allowing it to consider "" as a valid fulfillment of `\d*`, your capture is completed before the number ever occurs.

You should at least specify one digit as mandatory (+) instead of optional (*) to make it start capturing the group.

To clarify, when a regular expression is compiled without errors, but does not capture anything for a specific group, that does not mean that the match was not successful.

It means that the match was successful *despite* having captured anything. That means that you are letting it go over that group by design.

For instance, in this piece of your own regular expression: `(([-+*%])?(\d*\.?\d*)?)*` you are saying that: I am expecting some optional symbol followed by a decimal number, even though that is optional as well. If nothing was found, it would be okay, though, so, dear RegExp engine, please don't bother yourself, because I don't care whether this occurred or not.

Let's break this down further:

- `\d*\.\d*` means that anything that has any number of digits (including none at all) with a dot in between. So, `0.`, `.`, `.123`, are all valid matches, as well as `2.1`.
- By making *that* optional, you are saying that even the **dot** is not necessary, so, `(\d*\.\d*)?` would match `""` (the empty string).
- By writing `([-+*%])?(\d*\.?\d*)?` you are saying that *should anything occur before the string matched above, it must be one of the four indicated symbols*. But, you are not necessitating that it must occur (because of the `?`). Also, since the above group could match the empty string, if the engine does not succeed in matching the string to anything useful, the presence of any of the indicated four symbols would mean that this group would still be a successful match. The whole of it, including the number.
- Now, by grouping the previous definition as `(([-+*%])?(\d*\.?\d*)?)*`, you are making even that optional, basically telling the regular expression engine that it would be okay if it did not look any further than the beginning of this definition for an answer.

So, how should you proceed? When should you make a group optional? You shoud make a group optional only with care, knowing that if the engine failed to match anything to this group, the statement would still be valid and you do not care for this value.

Also, as a side note, you should not be capturing just about everything. Only capture the values that are ciritcal to you, because the engine will hold `(start,length)` pairs for any group you request in-memory, and that would cost you performance. Instead of the normal grouping `()`, use the **non-capturing group** indicator `(?:)` which will allow you grouping and a higher level of control, while preserving the memory.

Another use of capturing groups, is for when you want to reference the matching contents in your regular expression:

```
<(\w+)>.*?</\1>
```

Which would capture an XML tag with its matching closing tag. Note also that the above example is for demonstration only and generally speaking parsing any sort of hierarchical document using regular expressions (except the most mundane of them) is a capital B, capital I, Bad Idea.

Comment: thanks so much. Changed one character and it works now.  btw: when you get back a group with a length of zero, I assume that it just means that that optional group was not successfully matched?

Comment: I just updated the answer with information and details that would give you (probably) more insight and would answer your question in this comment.